# Can I use override permissions in rsync and store original in xattrs?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, rsync, symbolic-link

I'd like to do a backup to a remote machine where I only have a normal user account, so I'm working with `--fake-super`.

`rsync` appears to create the files on the server with permissions similar to the local ones, so symlinks end up as regular files with 777 permissions and an extended attribute that says "this should have been a symlink".

Obviously, that is bad on a multiuser system, because as long as they can enter the directory I keep my backup in, they can modify symlink targets.

Is there a way to have rsync create the backup files with a restrictive permission set?

Comment: But they can't enter the directory you keep the backup in, can they?

Comment: @grawity, no, but from a defense in depth standpoint I'd rather not have everything depend on a single bit if I can avoid it.

Comment: Do these symlinks have 777 perms on the original system?  If so, is that not also a problem?

Comment: @JimL., all symlinks show up with 777 permissions normally, but their permissions are normally ignored because you need write permission on the directory to modify them. `rsync` stores them as files on the other side though.

Comment: Argh!  Can't get newlines where I want them....  `$ date > /tmp/bar
$ chmod 400 /tmp/bar
$ ln -s /tmp/bar .
$ ls -l bar
lrwx--x---  1 jim  jim   8 Feb 22 11:43 bar@ -> /tmp/bar
$ ls -lL bar
-r--------  1 jim  jim  29 Feb 22 11:43 bar`

Comment: My oversight.  I just realized this problem is Linux-specific (hence your inclusion of the `linux` tag!).  Other Unices don't have this problem.